# Pywin31-214 not found on PYPI Pip download

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to download Py32 using Pip. It is listed on PYPI here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32/214

I am trying to install it using the standard pip syntax of:

```
pip2.7 install pywin32-214
```

This produces the following error message in Command Shell:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip2.7 install pywin32-214
Downloading/unpacking pywin32-214
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32-214
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pywin32-214
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Oleg Salenko\pip\pip.log
```

If I try using the syntax:

```
pip2.7 install pywin32
```

I get the following error message instead:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip2.7 install pywin32
Downloading/unpacking pywin32
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32
    Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pywin32 to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pywin32
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Oleg Salenko\pip\pip.log
```

Can anyone see what the issue is here and how I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: try `pip2.7 install pywin32 --allow-external pywin32 --allow-unverified pywin32` or `pip2.7 install http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok will try now. i have a fairly good idea what that will do, but could you walk it home for me just so im crystal clear? thanks.

Comment: the first command allows you to install externally hosted packages, the second is using the package directly from sourceforge, the sourceforge file should be `http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.zip/download`. If you go to the download page at sourceforge there are also .exe packages.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the first option threw up the same error as my original question and the second option threw up the error:     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid s
tart byte

Comment: i know vaguely about the character restrictions around unicode characters in Command Prompt, but im not sure which character is the offending one?

Comment: the second link is incorrect, I added the correct one in another comment, `pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.zip/download`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok that seemed to go through an installation, then when it got to the 'Cleaning up...' line it through up the following error:Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\use
rs\\olegsa~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-u6kkgg-build\\setup.py';exec(compile(get
attr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, '
exec'))" install --record c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-dm_wfq-record
\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile

Comment: failed with er
ror code 1 in c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-u6kkgg-build
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Oleg Salenko\pip\pip.log

Comment: did you try the .exe file http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe/download

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what do i do with a .exe for a python module? ive never installed via that method. thanks

Comment: just download and double click to install, are you using a 64 or 32 bit python?

Comment: actually ignore that, i clicked on it and it went through an installation process, however it then threw up the following error right at the end: 'close failed in file object destructor Error in sys.excepthook: Original exception was:'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56564/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-user3045351).

Comment: it seems to have installed though, so im wondering if that was just a bug with the .exe

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need to install from `pip` for some reason, I'd highly recommend grabbing the [`pywin32` installer here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. Everything is already compiled and ready to go, and in my experience nearly all of the installers there just work. You'll need to be using the python.org version of Python, though.